# How to print taxonomy terms in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I am trying to print taxonomy terms using this code:

```
<?php foreach ((array)$taxonomy as $item) { ?>
<a href="<?php print base_path() . "taxonomy/term/" . $item->tid; ?> "class='tags'><?php print $item->name ?>,</a>
<?php } ?>
```

It works fine in teaser, however it doesnt in the full node, the tags are empty in the full node. Can any one tell me what is the reason for this and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you give this code more context?  Where is `$taxonomy` coming from?

Comment: Its stored in $node->taxonomy.

Comment: What version of drupal are you using?, Where have you added the code you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I'd like to post my Drupal 6 solution.

Use this

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
```

Then loop through it to print out the terms:

```
      foreach ($tree as $term) {
       $path = taxonomy_term_path($term);
       $content .= '<a href="<?php print base_path() . strtolower(str_replace( " ", "-",$term->name)) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';           
  }
```